# How to Post Registration Form with File to ASP.NET MVC Action

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I'm unclear as to why I'm unable to POST the data in my form to the server. It appears as though the form is defaulting to a 'GET' request although I've hardcoded both the form and the AJAX call to use a 'POST' request. So, I'm out of ideas. Any suggestions are very much appreciated.

The UI looks like this:
[image]

This is my Javascript code:

```
            SubmitRegisterForm: function (e) {
                var scope = this;

                e.preventDefault();

                //var formData = new FormData();
                //formData.append('profilepic', $('#profilepic')[0].files[0]);

                var data = {
                    FirstName: $('#FirstName').val(),
                    LastName: $('#LastName').val(),
                    Email: $('#Email').val(),
                    Password: $('#Password').val(),
                    ConfirmPassword: $('#ConfirmPassword').val(),
                    StripeConnectedAcctId: scope.stripeConnectedAccountId                   
                };

                console.log(data);

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Account/Register',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: { model: data, profilepic: $('#profilepic')[0].files[0] },
                    enctype: 'multipart/form-data'
                }).done(function (resp) {

                });
            }
```

**Server-side code looks like this, but isn't currently being hit (that would be the problem bub):**
[image]

Also, I'm seeing these errors on the Chrome Dev tools Console:
[image]

Funny enough, the Javascript code executes fine, displaying the `data` variable just fine, but complains about some `Illegal Invocation` in Vue... which literally makes no sense as I don't even use any Vue related functions but rather issue an AJAX call.

What on God's green Earth gives???? >=/

I'm hoping I'll wake up to this with a solution in my inbox like it's Christmas!

Answer (score 0):

You are using ASP .NET so if you are using server side rendering I would do something like this and let the framework handle everything.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-action="controllorAction" method="post">
        <label class="form-label" for="firstName">First Name</label><input type="text" asp-for="Model.FirstName" />
        <label class="form-label" for="lastName">Last Name</label><input type="text" asp-for="Model.LatName" />
        ...
       <label class="form-label" for="customFile">Profile Picture</label><input type="file" asp-for="Model.File" class="form-control" id="File" />
       <input type="submit" value="Submit form" class="btn btn-primary" />
 </form>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/ASp/webpages_forms.asp
Hope this helps you